# What is causing 'non-hashable type' error?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, visual-studio-code

I have been farting around with a music player project in Python and I have created a nested dictionary of {'album':{'tracks':{trackID:{length:00, title:'name', 'artist'}}}}

trackID and length are of type int and everything else is strings.

I am getting this error - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE.  When I execute this code in one file window in (my main program), it doesn't work (gives me the above mentioned error), but then when I execute it in another window (from a test file), it works as expected.  I am using the latest Python 3.7.4 and all my libraries are up to date.  I'm also using Mac OS Mohave 10.14.6.

```
if trackID in musicDict["albumName"]["tracks"].keys()
    print (str(trackID) + " found!")
```

I can't figure out why the result would be different from one file window to the other.  I'm thinking there may be something somewhere else in the code causing this and it's not showing up as an error, maybe?

If you need more details, I will try to provide.  I'm new to Python and this one has me stumped...

Comment: post the full error you are getting please. Part of the error message shows the exact line of code that caused it...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/Shared/toms-music/music-player-tk.py", line 244, in populate_songlist
    if trackID in musicDict[playlist]['tracks'].keys():
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: After further debugging, I discovered that during execution the declared global variable 'playlist' was being recast from a string type to a list type.

So now I am using:

```if trackID in musicDict[playlist[selectedPlaylist]['tracks'].keys():```

and it works.